# Sound jumping back and forth

Tags: audio

So my issue is that whenever I play an mp3 from the pi the sound starts jumping back and forth.

So the audio starts playing it jumps forwards 5 seconds and after a few seconds it jumps back to where it originally jumped from.

How can I fix this? I already tried updating formware and software.

Edit:
When playing an mp3 file with ffplay
It gives us some output which look like errors.
Take a look at it here: https://pastebin.com/v9drjEA2

Comment: What software are you using to play the mp3? Try omxplayer.

Comment: I wrote a program in python which uses pygame mixer to play audio, but I also tried it with mpg321 and the same issue happens

Comment: Alright I have just tried it, and the same issue applies there

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem with the software you wrote. Try it on another machine (PC) and see if it does the same. If it does, post the code and perhaps someone can help.

Comment: If I play a song on the command line with omxplayer or mpg321 and the same issue happens it means that it is a system wide issue

Comment: Also tried running it with ffplay same issue but it gave me some output that may lead us to the solution (edited question with pastebin link to output)

Comment: start playing an mp3 file and unplug the keyboard, mouse and lan cable ... does it still skip?

Comment: There is not keyboard and mouse plugged into it, also I don't see how this would help, but I could try unplugging the lan cable
Edit: tried it, still skips

Comment: Maybe your mp3 filed are corrupt?

Comment: They work correctly on my pc and my laptop and my phone so I doubt that that is the case (It isn't just one file, but a library of my music)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone who tried to help me.
I figured it out on my own. (Or I guess you could say with CoderMike's help)

So what was the problem you may ask?
It was not with my program.
It was not with the players (ffplay, omxplayer, or whatever)

It was with the program I used to sync my music from google drive to the pi.
It corrupted the mp3 files.